# ngTableParams not working and got an error that length of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs ngTable with filter. When i run the page no table has displayed instead of showing table it showed me an error that says "length of undefined" .

My code snippet is:

```
var data=$scope.users;
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10,          // count per page
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
    }
}, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        // use build-in angular filter
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
            $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
            data;

        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

Here '$scope.users' is my array of json objects.
I got an error in line: `{total:data.length}`,

Here is the keyword that show me a response like this "length of undefined".

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: The error is straightforward: `data` variable is not defined.